# How to get the fields keyup and change inside the form

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get what all fields(input,select) are changed during keyup and change inside the form.

I did like this for onchange. But I need both keyup and change... (Any changes on the field need to update via ajax)

```
$("form#frm_job").find('input,select').change(function() {
   var field_value = $(this).val();
    ....
    ....

});
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use **on()** + multiple events binding:

```
$("form#frm_job").find('input,select').on('change keyup', function() {...
```

Comment: Thank you, I am using the version 1.4.2. So I have used 'live' instead of 'On'